# How to detect mouse events on adjacent elements in HTML that are covered

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to detect mouse events on an object that is adjacent (not a child for) but under another element in my HTML?

For example:

```
<style>
#test, test2 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%
}
</style>

<html>
    <section class="full" id="test">
    Full Screen 
    </section>


    <section class="anotherFull" id="test2">
    Full Screen As well
    </section>


<script>

        var elem = document.querySelector('#test2');

        elem.addEventListener('hover', function(){
          alert('you are hovering');
        }, false);

</script>
<html>
```

If I however over the page, regardless if I use `mouseenter` `mouseover` or `hover`, and no matter how far down I look in the `e` (from `document.addEventListener('hover', function(e){}, false)`; (like `e.target` etc. I can't detect a hover on the second (adjacent) element.

Comment: There is, you could set `pointer-events:none` to the element covering it, but that has the side-effect of not firing any mouse events on the overlying element.

Comment: You need to register the event to that adjacent element.

Comment: If the first overlays the second, you could use a `z-index` to bring the second to the top.

Comment: This is a rather poor example. Both sections have the same id and there is no given css or structure here.

Comment: I misunderstood your post (see answer below). Can you add an embedded code snippet showing all factors in play?

Comment: @TravisJ Sorry for the weak code example. I have improved it.

Comment: @StaticVoid this is what I ended up doing, although it did affect other styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/codk8axs/)***

One way to address this would be to simply chain the events. You can do this with a combination of addEventListener and dispatchEvent. It is outlined in an MDN article named **[Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)**

```js
var
 outer = document.getElementById("outer"),
 inner = document.getElementById("inner")
;

inner.addEventListener('mouseenter',function(e){
 alert('hovering inner');
},false);

outer.addEventListener('mouseenter',function(ev){
 alert('hovering outer');
 this.style.display = "none";
 var tar = document.elementFromPoint(ev.clientX, ev.clientY);
 this.style.display = "block";
 tar.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseenter'));
},false);
```

```css
#screen{
    position:relative;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
#outer{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:2;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
}
#inner{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Screen Mockup</legend>
    <div id="screen">
        <div id="outer"></div>
        <div id="inner"></div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: This is clever, but will only work if you know that the elements are overlapping. If you need to detect elements overlapping you'll probably need to use something like `document.elementFromPoint` in some fashion.

Comment: @gfullam - That is correct. If you do not know that inner is beneath outer, you need to *detach* outer, look for document.elementFromPoint from the event inside of outer's mouseover event, and the trigger the event based on the match from elementFromPoint. That approach will work, I have done it before. Your example indicated you knew the underlying element.

Comment: Here is a similar solution that uses `document.elementFromPoint` to detect overlap and hover: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17819021/2502532

Comment: @gfullam - See edit which shows the detach, elementFromPoint, dispatch process.

Comment: The update works well if the elements are entirely overlapping, but if they are partially overlapping, depending on which way the mouse enters, the events aren't triggered as expected. Here is a version of your example using `mousemove` to repeat the overlap check while the user traverses the element dispatching `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events on the covered element only where they overlap. http://codepen.io/gfullam/pen/vEgdjX

Answer (score 0):

Your post is unclear so I'll give a couple sugesstions.

If you're just trying to find out how to bind a hover event to the sibling of some known selector...

### JavaScript

```
var el = document.getElementById('test').nextElementSibling;
el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){...});
```

### CSS

```
#test+section:hover {
    ...
}
```

*NOTE: HTML `id` attributes must be unique. So your markup shouldn't contain two elements with the same `id`.*

Comment: `el` will be `#text` because there is whitespace. even if you add the event listener, it will not fire because it is never hovered due to the other element layered over it. This in no way addresses how to detect events from an element which is covered.

Comment: You're right about the whitespace node. Changed to `.nextElementSibling` instead. Also, I didn't gather that the item was covered. When the OP stated "(not a child for) but under", I took that to mean the next element down in the source code. I don't think the OP was very clear and this was a good faith effort.

Comment: I am sorry. I realize the problem with this answer:
The issue is not selecting the covered element. I could easily just add the listener directly to the element by its ID.  The issue is that the mouse events are not detected (even if that element has a listener added) because its adjacent sibling is receiving all of the mouse events.

Comment: Fair enough. It wasn't clear to me until you posted your code that your elements were actually positioned on top of each other. This doesn't address that problem; it just shows how to bind to an element whose selector is ambiguous, but you know the id of its previous sibling.